# Virtual Method vs. Abstract Class Member

Tags: c++, interfaces

Suppose we are writing an interface class which has some "properties" and "operations."  Assume also that every concrete implemented of the interface must contain the same set of properties.

There are two ways (that I see) of expressing this interface in code:

**Option 1**

```
class Interface
{
public:
    virtual void doSomething1() = 0;
    virtual int doSomething2(int) = 0;

    virtual int property1() const = 0;
    virtual char property2() const = 0;
};
```

**Option 2**

```
class Interface
{
public:
    virtual void doSomething1() = 0;
    virtual int doSomething2(int) = 0;

    int property1() const { return property1_; }
    char property2() const { return property2_; }

protected:
    Interface(int a, char b) : property1_(a), property2_(b) {}

private:
    int property1_;
    char property2_;
};
```

Is there a particular advantage to choosing one option over the other?

One reason I can see to use *option 2* is a decrease in the size of the vtable.  This might seem trivial, but on a storage-constrained system (e.g., and embedded MCU), if there are many implementations of the interface, a few bytes less for every vtable can go a long way. (I have proven this in production code)

Comment: The former allows for more lattitude in actual implementation, at the cost of virtual dispatch to access the "properties".

Answer (score 4):

These two classes are not semantically equivalent, so I recommend to make a decision based on the intended semantics, not on some technical criterion like the vtable size.

In #1, the methods `property1` and `property2` don't have a default implementation. When one derives a child class, the child class must implement those methods, and it is totally up to the child how it will do this - maybe similar to #2 using "backing fields" `property1_` and `property2_`, or quite differently, by returning calculated values, constant or throwing an exception undr certain circumstances.

In #2, there is an implementation with backing fields given, and child classes cannot change the implementation.

Note there could be also option #3, where the properties are implemented like in #2, but made virtual, so a child class can either use the default implementation from the base class or not.

Which design one should choose depends on the context:

- when one expects to have different child classes where the "backing field" implementation is all what's needed, one uses #2.
- when one wants child classes to provide their own implementation, one uses #1.
- and when one wants to allow child classes to use "backing field" implementation in most (or at least several) cases, but having the option of providing a different implementation, one uses #3.